# HTML Link not working with my quotations

Tags: html

So I am starting to learn HTML and I am running into some weird things. I am trying to just use a link to go to a specific webpage. I typed in the code but it gave me an error saying it could not find the link on my desktop. However, when I copy and paste the exact same code from a website it works fine. Here are the two codes so you can compare, the top one works and the bottom one doesn't.

```
<a href="https://www2.housing.wisc.edu/dining/ordering/">This is a link</a>
<a href=“https://www2.housing.wisc.edu/dining/ordering/”>This is a link</a>
```

I was wondering if it had to do with the slightly different quotation marks, if it is I am still not sure how to fix it, because the computer autocorrects the quotations to that format.

Comment: _"I was wondering if it had to do with the slightly different quotation marks"_ This

Comment: Find out how to turn off or override the autocorrection--or change the code in notepad and paste it back.

Answer (score 0):

If the comments haven't answered your question yet, yes you need to use a slightly different quotation mark. HTML only accepts the single typewriter (non-curly) quotation mark `' '` or the double one `" "`. Or, in your case, you can choose not to use quotes at all, unless the value contains a space or equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using? Office? Open up a text editor like Notepad or download Notepad++ (free) and you won't have to deal with auto correct.

In any case the code you posted above works for me.

Open Notepad.

copy and paste

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://www2.housing.wisc.edu/dining/ordering/">This is a link</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

click SAVE AS and instead of saving as a .txt file save as a .html to your Desktop.

Double click the newly created file, and it should open in a web browser.(If not you have to right click on the file and select "open with..." and choose a web browser

Click the link.